# MariaDB installation fails with no package available

Tags: mysql, installation, mariadb

I would like to install MariaDB version 5.5.56 on CENTOS 7(EC2 Instance). I tried using the command

```sh
sudo yum install MariaDB-server-5.5.56
```

But it says the package is unavailable. I need this specific version of MariaDB and I cant seem to find the solution.

If I run `sudo yum install MariaDB-server`, `yum` installs the 5.5.60 version.

Need guidance on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most reliable way is to download the tarball [from the official site](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/5.5.56/) and make it from source. It's more complicated than getting it through a package manager, but downgrading [is not officially supported](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/downgrading-between-major-versions-of-mariadb/), and if you run into issues there's little help available from them.

To do that, you can use the instructions for setting up a proper build environment, found [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/Build_Environment_Setup_for_Linux/). Once that's done, you can follow the instructions [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/generic-build-instructions/) to build the software.

If you still want to use `yum`, MariaDB does have an archive; it can be found [here](http://archive.mariadb.org/). Follow the instructions listed [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/yum/#pinning-the-mariadb-repository-to-a-specific-minor-release) to configure `yum` to only grab the specific minor release you want. Just from a quick look, [this link](http://archive.mariadb.org/mariadb-5.5.56/) is a good place to start.

I've pasted their example configuration below, with some alterations to show you a better idea of what it would look like.

```
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB-server-5.5.56
baseurl=http://archive.mariadb.org/mariadb-5.5.56/yum/centos7-amd64
gpgkey=http://archive.mariadb.org/mariadb-5.5.56/yum/centos7-amd64/rpms/MariaDB-5.5.56-centos7-x86_64-server.rpm
gpgcheck=1
```

Once done, you run

```
sudo yum clean metadata
```

and try to install as normal.

Comment: can we run it from the centos 7 using yum install?

Comment: @MadhuraMhatre I updated to include instructions for `yum install`.

Comment: I tried this but when I tried to start using systemctl start mariadb. It failed with below error- 
Failed to start mariadb.service: Unit not found.

Comment: @MadhuraMhatre I can't remember which version had this issue, but for some older installs of MariaDB, the service name was still called `mysql`

Answer (score 0):

if you get No package MariaDB-Galera-server available. Check file /etc/yum.conf, if my case there was a string: exclude=ansible1.9,mysql,mariadb,mariadb-*,Percona-XtraDB-*,Percona-*-55,Percona-*-56,Percona-*-51,Percona-*-50 Just comment this string and install goes well.